# trying to use shtml, not working

Tags: html, apache, ssi, shtml

I have included "Includes" and "AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml" to my httpd.conf file  tag, and wrote `<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->` in my shtml file, but when I run it the date doesn't show up. Any ideas why? Thank you.

This is in my conf file Directory tag in Apache Web Server folder:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might be having the same issue, my issue did not have anything to do with the set up process, what I did above was necessary and fine. I was just viewing the page via "file://", very silly mistake. When viewing via http://localhost it worked (of course).